# С помощью чего можно сделать такую карту

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать такую карту но проблема в том что все подписи должны иметь эффект плавного появления при долистывания до блока и должно быть адаптивно, хотел использовать какую нибудь библиотеку для построения графиков и использовать тип карт но нужно максимально простую, что бы можно было корректировать эти точки в дальнейшем.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: карты мира есть готовые - просто напишите в любом поисковике вот так "карта мира в svg" как я и сделал : https://mapsvg.com/maps/world скачиваете и ставите свои точки куда угодно

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что самый оптимальный и простой вариант решения:

1. Создать изображение с картой без точек.
2. Расположить ее в каком-нибудь элементе.
3. В том же элементе добавить сверстанные точки стран с абсолютным в процентах положением на этом изображении. Так получается, что эти точки будут адаптивно перемещаться, при изменении их общего контейнера.
4. Добавить с помощью скрипта, анимацию fadein при определнном событии (пролистывании до блока)